# Linux kernel register_chdev returned value

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, kernel-modules, raspbian, character-device

[This video](https://youtu.be/h7ybJMYyqDQ) shows an example Raspberry Pi Linux kernel module which creates a new character device. It uses the kernel API `register_chdev`. In a comment to the video (I can not generate a direct link to it), as regards the return value of `register_chdev`, the author states:

> If the return value is not equal to 0, the device number is already in use. The upper 12 bits of the return value are your major device number, the lower 20 bits are the minor device number.

I guess that by "the device number is already in use" he means "the non-zero major device number arbitrarily chosen in the kernel module is already in use".

Despite several webpages deal with this ([the official one](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API---register-chrdev.html), then [this one](https://www.cems.uwe.ac.uk/%7Eirjohnso/coursenotes/lrc/device/character/cd2.htm) and [this one](https://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x569.html)), I did not find any information about this internal subdivision of the return value.

If I choose to create (with my kernel module) a device with a major number already in use, the kernel does never accept it and refuses to register the device. This occurs both when the major number I chose is the same as the one of a block device, and when the major number I choose is the same as the one of a character device. `register_chdev` always return a negative value. In the latter case, instead, I was expecting a positive non-zero return value, with the upper 12 bits representing the major device number, and the lower 20 bits representing the minor device number (maybe greater than 0: if the major number was already used, maybe the system already had at least a device related to it, with the minor number 0).

Is it true what is stated in the Youtube comment? Where can I find some documentation about it?

---

I'm running Raspbian 10, `uname -a` shows:

```
Linux raspberrypi 5.10.63-v7+ #1459 SMP Wed Oct 6 16:41:10 BST 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Have you considered checking the [source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/char_dev.c#L247) instead of youtube videos and comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`register_chrdev` itself isn’t documented in the kernel, but [its definition is short](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.15/source/include/linux/fs.h#L2835):

```c
static inline int register_chrdev(unsigned int major, const char *name,
                  const struct file_operations *fops)
{
    return __register_chrdev(major, 0, 256, name, fops);
}
```

which basically means it calls [`__register_chrdev`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API---register-chrdev.html) to register a major with a full range of minors (256 minors starting at 0), and return that function’s result. The latter is documented as

> If *`major`* == 0 this functions will dynamically allocate a major and return its number.
>
> If *`major`* > 0 this function will attempt to reserve a device with the given major number and will return zero on success.
>
> Returns a -ve errno on failure.

There’s no provision for returning minors, encoded or otherwise. The purpose of these functions is to register a major in any case, potentially with a subset of minors; not a single minor.

The *encoding* comes into play when the device driver handles an `open` call, or any other time it needs to determine what minor (and perhaps major, if it handles multiple majors) a given device corresponds to. A driver is given the inode it’s asked to handle; for a device node, that includes the device number, which encodes the major and minor. The [`MAJOR`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.15/source/include/linux/kdev_t.h#L10) and [`MINOR`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.15/source/include/linux/kdev_t.h#L11) macros, or starting from an inode, the [`imajor`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.15/source/include/linux/fs.h#L880) and [`iminor`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.14.15/source/include/linux/fs.h#L875) functions, should be used to extract the values.

Some character devices offer multiplexing on top of the major registration mechanisms described above; see [How does one misc driver control all this different hardware?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/659980/86440) for an example of this.